# PHP attempt to update a MySQL database doesn't update anything

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have my code below to update a my MySQL database, it's running but is not updating the database when I check rcords using phpmyadmin. plae hlp me.

```
$database = "carzilla";

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$manufacturerTable = $_POST[vehicleManufacturer];
$numberToSearch = $_POST[vehicleIdNo];
$engineType = $_POST[engineType];
$engineCC = $_POST[engineCC];
$year = $_POST[year];
$numberofDoors = $_POST[numberofDoors];
$tireSize = $_POST[tireSize];
$chasisNumber = $_POST[chasisNumber];
$vehicleMake = $_POST[vehicleMake];
$price=$_POST[price];

mysql_select_db("$database", $con);

$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE $manufacturerTable SET username='vehicleMake', 
engineType='$engineType', engineCC='$engineCC', year='$year', chasisNo='$chasisNumber', numberOfDoors='$numberofDoors' ,numberOfDoors='$numberofDoors',  tireSize='$tireSize', price='$price' WHERE `index` ='$id'");

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
{
 die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'record has been successfuly';

mysql_close($con);


?>
```

Comment: Dude, your PHP is vulnerable to SQL injections in almost every possible ways. You *really* should not trust what comes in your `$_POST` like you do.

Comment: Your query has a `WHERE index = '$id'`, but I see no `$id` being set in your code. Do you really mean to update an existing record or are you trying to create a new one?

Comment: need to see sql table structure

Comment: @Romin...Thanks I'll check abt that. That was ayping error, twas meant to be there.

Comment: http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: @Julien: no, I really don't want to see the table structure! There is sufficient evidence from the code that its a mess (a very long way from being normalized)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a good look at your query.   You are referring to PHP variables in several different fashions in the same statement.  In the query $manufacturerTable is just $manufacturerTable, you encase a few others in single quotes, some of which you remove the $ from, others you do not.  I know I preach this far too often, but you should really look into using prepared statements.  They take all the guess work out of using variables in your queries, and they prevent you from being victimized by injection hacks.  But the short answer here is that you are not referencing your variables correctly in the query.

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes putting the variables directly in the syntax can cause issues. Have you tried to use concatenation for the query.

```
$query = "UPDATE ".$manufacturerTable." SET username='vehicleMake', engineType='."$engineType."', engineCC='".$engineCC."', year='".$year."', chasisNo='".$chasisNumber."', numberOfDoors='".$numberofDoors."' ,numberOfDoors='".$numberofDoors."',  tireSize='".$tireSize."', price='".$price."' WHERE index =".$id;

$sql = mysql_query($query); # this should be put in the if else
```

If index is number based you do not need the '' surrounding it. Plus is username='vehicleMake' or is it a variable. if it is a variable, add the $ or use concatenation like the rest. Your SQL check should be something like follows.

```
if (mysql_query($query))
{
 echo 'record has been successfuly';
} else {
 die('Error: ' . mysql_error() . ' | ' . $query);
}
```

The reason you export the query is so you can try it manually to make sure it works and what error you may be getting. phpMySQL can show a different error then the mysql_error() at times

Plus you should be escaping all input that is user entered using mysql_escape_string() or mysql_real_escape_string()

Comment: anyone that down voted like to explain. I have had issues with adding variables directly with no concatenation depending on php/mysql version

Comment: Why the down vote? @ James williams. Thanks for the code. It's working

Comment: Didn't downvote, but suggesting changing `$var = "blah $var blah"` to `$var = "blah " . $var . " blah"` is a utterly pointless. They will both end up with the exact same result in $var. All you've done is made the query string far more complicated and far more likely to product a syntax error (both in PHP **AND** SQL) due to misplaced quotes.

Comment: @MarcB depending on server setup it can make a difference. It did work for Ukavi

Comment: What server setup? PHP syntax works the same no matter what server you're on.

Comment: @MarcB I have worked on shared, dedicated, and home brew servers. I have had to change it depending on the server and what it is setup.  http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single does state that variables will not expand in a string

Comment: @MarcB Even my MAMP setup has different ways to initiate php code versus regular code and has to be coded a certain way. Apache on one server is not always the same as another server as well. There are different configuration options that can be changed to cause things to work differently. One comparision between 2 shared hosting prov: GoDaddy/1and1. I can write code to work on 1and1 and have to rewrite it (even though I am using standard php functions and calls) to work on GoDaddy.

Comment: @james: uh, yeah. on single-quoted strings. Double-quoted strings are parsed for variables and their values interpolated. OP is using a double-quoted string.